# MarkupString cast is still encoding string

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've found numerous examples of how to use MarkupString and it's just not doing what it's supposed to.

In my blazor component I have:

```
            <small class="help-text editable-label" @ref="HelpText">
                @(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.HelpText) ? (MarkupString)Model.HelpText : "Double-click here to add text")
            </small>
```

I have a simple model right now where I initialize HelpText to

```
"<b><i>This is a test</b></i>"
```

In my webpage I get that exact output displayed.  (See attached picture).

Comment: I assume under no circumstance is the value of `Model.HelpText` ever supplied by an end-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually do to the vagaries of `?:`.  Somehow the MarkupString value is converted to `object?` and then to `string` again.

To be honest I was surprised your code compiles, the two branches of `?:` must be 'assignment compatible', and MarkupString cannot be assigned to string.

You can do this:

```html
<small class="help-text editable-label" @ref="HelpText">
  @((MarkupString)(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelHelpText) ? ModelHelpText : "Double-click here to add text"))
</small>
```

but that is getting so ugly I would move it to the @code section.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because I did realize I need to do the cast on the outside of the ternary operator.  I'm actually surprised it compiled now, too.